# Numbers.app Chart Trendline Equation Capture

Tags: numbers

I have a set of data that creates a chart.  It's a growth chart.  I the chart to display the **Trendline**.

**y = 55x - 1234**

Is there a formula that captures that equation?  Having to re-enter those values every time the source data changes, is a pain.

Any insight appreciated.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two functions, each capturing one of the coefficients in a linear regression: SLOPE() and INTERCEPT(). Below is the screenshot of an example spreadsheet and formulas inside:

[image]

P.S. Mind the semicolons in the formulas in the screenshot. The formulas have the semicolon as the argument separator because the decimal point in my computer at this time is a comma.